# Orthonormal frame bundle orthogonal to a curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fibre-bundles

This is a duplicate of [this question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604508/orthonormal-frame-bundle-orthogonal-to-a-curve), since I got there not a single answer.

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional smooth riemannian manifold and $\varphi\colon(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow M$ an embedding. $\varphi$ will denote the image of $\varphi$, too.

Consider the bundle of $(n-k)$-frames in the normal bundle of $\varphi$, where $k>2$. The fiber of this bundle is the orthonormal stiefel manifold $V_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$. This bundle is trivial by fixing one fiber and transporting it over the bundle via parallel transport of the Levi-Civita connection of $M$ along $\varphi$.

Now take a global section $\eta$ of this bundle and consider the bundle of orthonormal $(k-1)$-frames in the normal bundle of $\varphi$, which are orthogonal to $\eta$. This gives me a bundle with fiber $V_{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1-(n-k)})=V_{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^{k-1})$.

I am searching for an argument to show, that this second bundle is also smoothly trivial. The proof considered before doesn't work, because parallel transport along $\varphi$ doesn't preserve beeing orthogonal to $\eta$ in general. Can someone help me out by giving me a hint how to manage that?

I don't want to use any classification results or any sophisticated bundle-theory. I think there must be an more-or-less elementary argument like the one of my first idea.

Comment: Actually, unless $\phi$ is a geodesic (up to parametrization), your first step won't work anyway, because parallel translation using the Levi-Civita connection won't preserve the $(n{-}1)$-plane bundle normal to the tangent bundle of the curve $\phi$ unless $\phi$ is a geodesic (up to reparametrization).  If you think about how you might modify the Levi-Civita connection along $\phi$ to get a connection on the ambient tangent bundle pulled back along $\phi$ that will preserve the induced metric as well as the tangent bundle to the curve, you will see how to solve both your problems at once.

Comment: Oh, of course you are right, my first step works only if $\varphi$ is a geodesic. You could maybe elaborate a bit about how to modify the connection appropriately in the way you suggested?

Comment: Sure.  The standard technique for doing this is to define a new connection as follows:  If $\nabla$ is the induced connection on $\phi^*(TM)$, the ambient tangent bundle along the curve, and you split it orthogonally as $\phi^*(TM) = T_\phi \oplus N_\phi$, then you define a new connection $\bar\nabla$ on $N_\phi$ by $\bar\nabla_X V = \pi_{N_\phi}(\nabla_X V)$, where $\pi_{N_\phi}:\phi^*(TM)\to N_\phi$ is the orthogonal projection.  Now, you can use $\bar\nabla$ instead of $\nabla$ for parallel transport, since this will preserve $N_\phi$.

Comment: I see. The new connection $\bar{\nabla}$ is a metric connection on $N_\varphi$, so parallel transport gives me isometries and everything is fine. As you mentioned, this solves my second problem immediately, since I can now split $N_\varphi$ in vectors tangent and vectors orthogonal to my global section and do the same trick again. Thanks a lot, Robert Bryant!